# VBA Powerpoint Reference a textbox with variable

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am attempting to write a vba loop that will detect the value of all ActiveX textboxes on the slide. However I am have trouble writing the code for the "variable" in the textbox reference. For example TextBox(i) needs to be referenced in the loop.  Where i is an integer I set the value to.

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to 4

 If IsNull(Slide1.Shapes.("TextBox" & i).Value) = True 
     Then (Slide1.Shapes.("TextBox" & i).Value) = 0
              Else: ...

Next i
```

However this script doesn't work and I have been unable to locate a source for how to properly code this variable portion of script. There has been some talk of using Me.Controls however I am not creating a form. Would anyone be willing to share what the error is here in my script?

Comment: Do you mean *specifically* Text Box shapes or do you mean any shape that has text in it (rectangles, circles etc can all include text)?

Comment: I specifically am referring to all the TextBoxes on the slide only. The word "Shapes" came from other scripts off the web. Perhaps "Shapes" isn't needed? I created the TextBoxes via ActiveX controls in Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve Rindsberg you had the correct code. Thank you. Here was the final script to obtain the value, and set the value if blank.

```
    For i = 1 To 4

            'set oSh to TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3... etc.
            Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i))

                'set myVar to value of this TextBox1, TextBox2...
                myVar = oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Value

                    If myVar = "" Then _
                        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Text" & CStr(i)).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0 _
                    Else: 'do nothing

                    'clear value of myVar
                    myVar = ""

    'start on next integer of i                
    Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

This will put the value of i into TextBox i.  Should get you started, I think.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To 4

        Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then  ' shape exists
            oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Text = CStr(i)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```